# How can I save a web page offline?

Tags: files, offline

I have this url : http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/China and wish to download as an offline document. How do I do that ?. 
I am taking that there is no wifi access in the place I intend to visit in China and hence this article would be useful to refer to as a 'offline document'.

I hope the question is clear enough for someone to assist me. Thank you

Comment: I've seen your edit and voted for reopening. Crucial documents like this, however, are better served printed physically, the way I see it.

Comment: Agreed with Andy, if I really wanted it digital I would probably print it to PDF and use that file.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has a download as offline feature in the side menu, for downloading sites as offline sites.

[image: download option]

<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: I think this is also another good workaround as long cache is not deleted, and definitely worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I had another workaround; since you want to convert this url to pdf, you could make use of the [UrlToPdf](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nop.urltopdf&hl=en) application from playstore.

It converts a webpage to a pdf document document​ (similar functionality to Adobe Acrobat pdf extension for chrome) and stores it offline

[image: a]. [image: b]